# Linq to objects find index and sum results

Tags: .net, linq

I have a collection of Tasks which contain a number of fields but more importantly Duration of type Int.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>;
tasks.Add(new Task{Name= 'Task 1', Duration = 3 });
tasks.Add(new Task{Name= 'Task 2', Duration = 2});
tasks.Add(new Task{Name= 'Task 3', Duration = 1});
tasks.Add(new Task{Name= 'Task 4', Duration = 4});
```

Given a task I want to find that task within the list and then sum anything that was before it.  Eg.  If my task I have is 'Task 3' then the result I want is 5 i.e. tasks before 'Task 3' is Task 1 and Task 2 with a duration of 3 and 2 respectively which equals 5.

Hopefully that makes sense and someone could provide the answer.  Hoping to do it with linq as opposed to just iterating the loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq's [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) extension method followed by [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx):

```
var result = tasks.TakeWhile(t => t.Name != "Task 3").Sum(x => x.Duration);
```

Comment: Are you serious....I just posted this and thought I wouldnt get an answer.  Two minutes later and bingo!!!  Thank you very much ...I will try it now!  Clearly I need to learn more linq and all its powerful goodness!

Comment: @GlenHong Never underestimate the power of Linq :p

Comment: Just out of interest I assume that linq is basically doing what I would normally do which is iterating the loop?  It just allows you to write less code?

Comment: @GlenHong Pretty much. It's equivalent to `int sum = 0; foreach(var t in tasks) if(t.Name != "Task 3") sum += t.Duration else break;`